# PDE $u_xy + 2u_x = 2x(1+2y)$ with BD $: u(0,y)=0, u(x,0)=x\exp(-x^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

Find a solution of the boundary value problem
PDE: $u_xy + 2u_x = 2x(1+2y)$
BD $: u(0,y)=0, u(x,0)=x\exp(-x^2)$

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Both partials are with respect to x. You can combine like terms, and get the answer by usual calculus techniques. But, are you sure that is right, both partials are with respect to x? There isn't one with respect to y as well somewhere ?

Comment: If so, then it just reduces to an ODE. A very familiar one...

Comment: @Max : There is probably a typo in $u_xy + 2u_x = 2x(1+2y)$ . Until it was corrected we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting the equation is actually $$u_{xy} + 2 u_{x} = 2 x(1+2y)$$ If that's the case, then this is an exercise in calculus. First rewrite
$$u_{xy} + 2 u_{x} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(u_y + 2 u\big)= 2 x(1+2y)$$ Set $w(x,y) = u_y(x, y) + 2\,  u(x,y)$. Then the equation becomes 
$$w_x = 2x (1+2y).$$ Integrated once with respect to $x$ you get $$w(x,y) = x^2(1+2y) + f(y)$$ for some smooth function $f(y)$. Since $u(0,y) = 0$, its first derivative with respect to $y$ can be calculated and is $u_y(0,y) = 0$ and thus $$w(0, y) = u_y(0,y) + u(0,y) = 0.$$
Consequently $$w(0,y) = f(y) \equiv 0$$ and therefore
$$u_y(x,y) + 2\, u(x,y) = w(x,y) = x^2(1+2y)$$ so we end up with the differential equation (linear and ordinary)
$$u_y + 2\,u =  x^2(1+2y)$$ To solve it, multiply both sides with $e^{2y}$
$$e^{2y} \, u_y + 2 \, e^{2y}\,u =  x^2(1+2y)e^{2y}$$ which by the product rule is the same as
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big(e^{2y} \, u\big) =  x^2(1+2y)e^{2y}$$ Integrate both sides
$$e^{2y} \, u(x, y) = g(x) + x^2 \, \int \, (1+2y) e^{2y} \, dy$$
$$u(x, y) = g(x) \, e^{-2y} + x^2 \,e^{-2y} \, \left(\int \, (1+2y) e^{2y} \, dy\right)$$  where $g(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth function. Perform the integration and get
$$u(x, y) = g(x) \, e^{-2y} + x^2 \,e^{-2y} \, e^{2y} \, y = g(x) \, e^{2y} + x^2 y  $$ Finally use the second boundary condition to determine $$u(x,0) = g(x) = x e^{-x^2}$$
The solution is $$u(x,y) = x e^{-x^2 - 2y} + x^2 y$$